# JAXRS resource: @Stateless or @RequestScoped

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I've created a jaxrs resource like this:

```
@Path(ReferenceEndpoint.PATH)
public interface ReferenceResource {

    @GET
    public Response download(
        @PathParam(ReferenceEndpoint.Download.Parameters.ID)
            String id
    );
}
```

I'm struggling with `@Stateless` and `RequestScoped` annotations.

```
javax.ejb.Stateless;
javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
```

I figure out what are they stand for, but I don't quite figure out why I see them in some code over there.

I mean, I've took a look over there, and sometimes I see `@Stateless`, but other times, `@RequestScoped`, and sometimes netiher of them.

Any lights?

Comment: Why do you want to use one/both of those annotations?